# Issue with Openshot after ugraded from 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: 20.04, openshot

I recently upgraded my laptop from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04. The upgrade went well but Openshot video editor had some issues.

So I uninstalled Openshot completely.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge openshot
```

Then I tried installing Openshot again

```
sudo apt-get install openshot
```

but I'm getting the following error.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
openshot : Depends: openshot-qt but it is not going to be installed
```

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I'll be grateful if I could get some help.

Edit:
Output of

```
openshot:
Installed: (none)
Candidate: 2.4.3+dfsg1-1
Version table:
 2.4.3+dfsg1-1 500
    500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
    500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages
 openshot-qt:
 Installed: (none)
 Candidate: 2.5.1+dfsg2+1218+202003032149~ubuntu20.04.1
 Version table:
  2.5.1+dfsg2+1218+202003032149~ubuntu20.04.1 500
    500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openshot.developers/ppa/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
    500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openshot.developers/ppa/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
 2.4.3+dfsg1-1 500
    500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
    500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages
```

Comment: Please run `sudo apt update` and add output of `apt-cache policy openshot openshot-qt` to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert Just edited my question with the output.

Answer (score 0):

You have to purge the PPA and use official packages instead.

Use the commands below:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:openshot.developers/ppa

sudo apt-get install openshot-qt
```

Comment: I'm getting same error.